# Is there any elegant way to call a web page asynchronously ,ignore the response and release resource of thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a case in **ASP.NET**,that when a request got, a web page (naming it as `service.aspx`)will be called asynchronously, and I don't care the response of `service.aspx`, I just need call it .

Right now ,I have two ways.
First one is `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse`, parameter callback is set as `null`. And it seems that it's not a good idea , there is no way to call `EndGetResponse`, so maybe the resource of calling `service.aspx` thread could not be released.
Second one is `WebClient.OpenReadAsync`, but I'm not sure whether it could release thread resource if I don't specify `OpenReadCompleted`  event.

Or maybe there is other appropriate way to have what I want.

Comment: If you are using http, I think there has to be a response before the connection is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that will make web requests in the background. Create a static instance of this class in your application's HttpApplication class (Global.asax) and then call a method to queue web requests as required.

**Class that performs web requests in the background**

```
public class SiteBackgroundCaller : IRegisteredObject, IDisposable
    {
        private BlockingCollection<string> requestList;

        private CancellationTokenSource queueWorkerCts;
        private Task queueWorkerThread;

        public SiteBackgroundCaller()
        {
            // Register an instance of this class with the hosting environment, so we can terminate the task gracefully.
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

            requestList = new BlockingCollection<string>();
            queueWorkerCts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            queueWorkerThread = new Task(queueWorkerMethod, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            queueWorkerThread.Start();
        }

        public void QueueBackgroundRequest(string uri)
        {
            requestList.Add(uri);
        }

        private void queueWorkerMethod()
        {
            while (!queueWorkerCts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    // This line will block until there is something in the collection
                    string uri = requestList.Take(queueWorkerCts.Token);

                    if (queueWorkerCts.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;

                    // Make the request
                    HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    // This may throw if the cancellation token is Cancelled.
                }
                catch (WebException)
                {
                    // Something wrong with the web request (eg timeout)
                }
            }
        }

        // Implement IRegisteredObject
        public void Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            queueWorkerCts.Cancel();
            queueWorkerThread.Wait();
        }

        // Implement IDisposable
        public void Dispose()
        {
            HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
        }
    }
```

**Instance of the class in HttpApplication (in Global.asax)**

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static SiteBackgroundCaller BackgroundCaller { get; private set; }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundCaller = new SiteBackgroundCaller();
    }
}
```

**Queuing a web request from a page**

```
public partial class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Global.BackgroundCaller.QueueBackgroundRequest("http://www.example.com/service.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the HttpWebRequest and not read the response:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("service.aspx");
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
   // typically here you would call GetResponseStream and read the content
}
```

you can also use the async variation:

```
using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
}
```